# Достаточно быстрый ввод-вывод

Tags: c#

Вот интересно, когда на всяких соревнованиях по программированию в условиях задачи пишут что-то типа:

> Note: Since input-output is large, prefer using fast input-output methods.

что это означает применительно к шарпу?

Допустим, часть задачи про ввод-вывод выглядит примерно так:

> Input Format
>
> The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the
> number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
>
> The first and only line of each test case contains six space-separated
> integers G1, S1, B1, and G2, S2, B2.

Как понять, достаточно ли быстро я делаю ввод-вывод, если я использую код типа:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var firstLine = Console.ReadLine();
    var testsCount = int.Parse(firstLine);

    for (int i = 1; i <= testsCount; i++)
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        var currentResult = Process(line);
        Console.WriteLine(currentResult.ToString());
    }
}
```

Сигнатура вызываемого метода:

```
 private static int OlympicsRanking(int[] nums) {}
```

Обычно на выходе либо число, либо строка YES/NO либо булево значение.

На входе в этом задании есть такой файл в качестве образца, это типа претест, потом запускается расчёт файла с 10 тысячами тестов в файле.

```
3
10 20 30 0 29 30
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Возможно имеется ввиду что можно сделать 1 вывод вместо нескольких выводов на консоль. В даном случае можно считать все необходимое в цикле а потом сделать вывод одной командой в консоль, например

Comment: @Andrew Вот думаю, что как раз наоборот - это замечание в основном про ввод, а не про вывод. Потому что на вход подаются огромные файлы (в некоторых криптографических задачах -- с кучей крупных простых чисел), алгоритм отрабатывает долго, но на выходе как правило одно небольшое число. Мне кажется, что логичнее как раз быстро считать большой файл, чем оптимизировать склейку небольших ответов.

Comment: Еще парсинг родной достаточно медленный. Думаю что его можно реализовать более быстро, если обьемы данных реально большие. https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int . Так же раз уж необходимо большие обьемы данных обрабатывать, вероятно будет хорошей идеей полностью отказаться от LINQ.

Comment: Что касательно задачи, так вы показали очень маленький кусок, оптимизировать наверное можно, но не понятно, что такое currentResult, непонятно, что вообще этот код делает, непонятно условие вывода (вы его тоже скрыли), выводить надо сразу после каждого тексткейза или можно сначала прочитать все, а потом вывести все? Пока больше вопросов, чем ответов.

Comment: @Andrew раз уж на то пошло, то ваш пример слишком медленный )) https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499547/12888024

Comment: @aepot Дополнил сигнатуру метода для данной конкретной задачи, а также что обычно бывает в таких случаях. Возможно, это достаточно снимает неопределённость? Просто подобных задач много, я не знаю как соблюсти баланс между черезчур конкретной задачей и общим описанием подобного класса задач.

Comment: Вы вводом/выводом собственноручно не занимаетесь, а используете библиотечную реализацию `ReadLine` / `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 6):

Способы ввода-вывода не делятся на "быстрые" и "медленные", потому что если бы это было так, все бы просто пользовались быстрыми, а смысла в медленных не было. Это касается не только соревнований, в реальных приложениях CLI также не отказались бы от способа считывать данные быстрее. Я думаю, авторы задачи в данном случае просто рекомендуют оптимизировать код под случай большого объема входных данных данных. Что это значит на практике? Тот код, который вы привели, можно было бы, теоретически, переписать вот таким образом:

```
static void Main()
{
    string str = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = str.Split(new char[]{'\r', '\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string firstLine = lines[0];
    int testsCount = int.Parse(firstLine);

    for (int i = 1; i <= testsCount; i++)
    {
        int[] line = lines[i].Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        //...
    }                        
}
```

(Эта реализация не сработает на живой консоли, так как конца ввода как такового не будет, но, я полагаю, что тысячи строк не будут вводить вручную. При перенаправлении ввода из файла все работает, так как концом ввода будет конец файла.)

В плане "алгоритмической" сложности этот способ в принципе аналогичен вашему. Однако, его отличает то, что в память считываются все входные данные целиком. Если объем данных станет сопоставимым с размером доступной оперативной памяти, начнется интенсивное вытеснение страниц памяти на жесткий диск и обратно, благодаря чему этот способ будет работать сильно медленнее, чем способ с построчным считыванием. На маленьких объемах данных эту проблему не обнаружить, вероятно, поэтому авторы задачи и предупреждают об этом отдельно. В целом же, выжать что-то, пытаясь оптимизировать ввод/вывод вряд ли получится. У вас можно разве что выкинуть LINQ и этим чуть ускорить за счет меньших расходов на вызовы по интерфейсам. Думаю, этот способ вполне можно назвать "быстрым" в данном контексте.

Comment: *"так как конца ввода как такового не будет"* - а как же Ctrl+Z/F6 в винде и Ctrl+D в линуксе?

Answer (score 6):

Как справедливо [заметил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1315727/178779) [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight), способы ввода не делятся на быстрые и медленные, поскольку вторые в языке не нужны. Однако, иногда из-за универсальности при вводе делается слишком много лишних действий, что может стать проблемой.

Как распознать проблему? Для начала, смотрите на (асимптотическую) сложность своего алгоритма. Если ваш алгоритм хотя бы квадратичный относительно исходных данных - можете смело наплевать на оптимизацию ввода-вывода, поскольку даже самый неоптимальный ввод-вывод всё равно остаётся линейным. А вот если ваш алгоритм имеет линейное время относительно входных данных - надо приглядеться к вводу-выводу по-внимательнее.

*И да, обратите внимание на уточнение "относительно исходных данных", это важно. К примеру, алгоритмы сложения матриц или обхода в ширину часто считаются квадратичными - но относительно объёма исходных данных они линейны!*

Обычно, когда говорят про медленный ввод-вывод, имеют в виду время самого ввода-вывода, то есть время проведённое в ожидании чтения данных с диска или перекладывания буферов в ядре ОС. Однако, на олимпиадах это время, как правило, не учитывается, поэтому важны лишь накладные расходы на каждый системный вызов. И здесь для пишущих на языке C# хорошая новость - стандартный [`StreamReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0) (а за консольным вводом стоит именно он) использует буферизованный ввод-вывод, экономя системные вызовы автоматически. Поэтому популярный трюк вида "читать файл в память целиком" обязательным не является (хотя иногда позволяет упростить некоторые другие трюки).

---

А вот вторая проблема серьёзнее, и имя ей парсинг. Стандартный вызов `int.Parse` делает достаточно много проверок, защитных и не очень:

1. проверяет используемую культуру (настройки глобализации), чтобы убедиться что знак числа надо искать перед числом и прочее - и эта проверка, вообще говоря, в общем случае является нужной - но на олимпиаде она лишняя;
2. избавляется от ведущих пробелов;
3. проверяет что в строке нет никаких мусорных символов, не являющихся цифрами;
4. проверяет возможность переполнения;
5. избавляется от пробелов в конце.

Подробнее алгоритм можно увидеть тут: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ec07ac8709dd5676084a79193cac9498eaa427ff/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Parsing.cs#L542-L718

Этот алгоритм довольно сильно оптимизирован - к примеру, он не делает проверку на переполнение если было менее 9 цифр, но в условиях олимпиады, когда заведомо известно что все входные данные корректны, он слишком избыточен. На моих бенчмарках он оказался в 6,5 раз медленнее примитивного алгоритма из средней школы:

```cs
int FastParsePositiveInteger(string s) 
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (var c in s)
        result = result * 10 + (c - '0');
    return result;
}
```

Поэтому, если оказалось необходимо ускорять ввод-вывод - в первую очередь надо писать свой парсинг для целых и вещественных чисел.

---

Наконец, последняя проблема - оптимизация перекладываний байтов в памяти. Обычно при чтении числа происходит следующее:

1. читаются байты из файлового потока;
2. преобразуются в символы декодировщиком с учётом кодировки;
3. символы перемещаются в строку, которая уже подаётся на вход парсера.

Получается, что весь входной файл так или иначе перекладывается в памяти три раза, хотя можно было бы перекладывать его всего один раз - ведь кодировка-то заведомо известна, и обычно она ASCII.

В итоге, если собрать эти оптимизации, получится что-то подобное:

```cs
class FastASCIIReader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream stream;
    private readonly byte[] buffer;
    private int offset, count;
    private bool eof;

    public FastASCIIReader()
    {
        this.stream = Console.OpenStandardInput(bufferSize: 1); // не забываем выключить внутренний буфер потока
        this.buffer = new byte[4096];
        this.offset = this.count = 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.stream.Close();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private void EnsureInput(int n)
    {
        Debug.Assert(n <= 64);

        if (offset + n > count && !eof)
            FillBuffer();
    }

    private void FillBuffer()
    {
        // считаем, что в конце буфера чтения не могло остаться слишком много непрочитанных байт благодаря проверке в EnsureInput
        if (count > offset)
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, buffer, 0, count - offset);
        count -= offset;

        var r = stream.Read(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            eof = true;
            r = 1;
            buffer[count] = 0; // добавляем в конец файла виртуальный нулевой байт для упрощения некоторых алгоритмов
        }
        count += r;
    }

    private static bool IsSpace(byte v) => v == ' ' || v == '\n' || v == '\r';
    private static bool IsDigit(byte v) => v >= '0' && v <= '9';

    public void SkipSpaces()
    {
        do
        {
            EnsureInput(1);
            while (offset < count && IsSpace(buffer[offset])) offset++;
        } while (offset == count);
    }

    public int ReadInt32()
    {
        SkipSpaces();
        EnsureInput(10);

        int sign = 1;
        int result = 0;

        if (buffer[offset] == '-')
        {
            sign = -1;
            offset++;
        }
        else if (buffer[offset] == '+')
        {
            offset++;
        }

        while (IsDigit(buffer[offset]))
        {
            result = result * 10 + buffer[offset] - '0';
        }

        return result * sign;
    }

    // тут другие методы чтения
}
```

Но я не рекомендую использовать подобных подход во всех задачах по умолчанию, и уж точно нельзя так писать в реальных приложениях.

Answer (score 2):

Поддержу идею MSDN.WhiteKnight о том что под "быстрый вывод" имеется ввиду оптимизировать работу кода для работы с большими обьемами данных.

Пути оптимизации:

- Отказ от построчной обработки/вывода - т.е. обработать относительно большой буферизированный кусок данных, а потом уже выводить его. (в консоль или файл - не суть)
- отказ от LINQ
- замена парсинга на кастомную реализацию [пример того на сколько медленная реализация родного парсинга](https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int) + [кастомная реализация парсинга от aepot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499547/12888024)  (не забываем там ему поставить плюсик за старания в написании этого быстрого низкоуровневого монстра)

Comment: Короче, правильно мне говорили, что всё это спортивное программирование мало имеет общего с чистым кодом, всё на спидах для разгона и вообще лучше писать на си если хочешь в соревнования. Хотя что ныть-то... ни разу не утыкался в лимит по обработке ввода-вывода, всегда оказывалось что как только переделаешь неоптимальный по времени алгоритм (условно: с O(N^2) на линейный и т.п.) проходил и с linq в коде чтения данных.